# How to print to only one column in an excel sheet using python panda

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file and I want to print data only to the "cars" column of this excel sheet. Is there any way I can do this using pandas module for python? I am searching through files and want to print the findings only in the cars column

[image: example]

This is all I have:

```
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\car.csv') 
 for line in data:
    if 'ferrari' in line.split() 
        cars = line.split()
        car_m = cars[1]
df['cars'] = car_m #doesn't work
```

Comment: df['Car:'] will give you the column value.

Comment: can i print to the column value somehow?

Comment: either just print as a list or loop around `print(df["Car."]) ` or
`for each_car in df["Car."]:
    print(each_car)`

Comment: print(df["Car:"].values)

Comment: pls update the question with the expected output you are looking for. on your last line it say does not work, elaborate pls. are you getting error ?

Answer (score 1):

The column name is wrong, it's not 'cars' but 'Car:'.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('car.csv') 

df['Car:'] = 'Ferrari'

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Name   Date     Car:
0  19GS  2-Dec  Ferrari
1  1A54  1-Feb  Ferrari
2  1AG5  1-Jan  Ferrari
3  1AH0  1-Feb  Ferrari
4  1AHG  4-Mar  Ferrari
```

If you want to set only 1 position you can use df.loc:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('car.csv') 

df.loc[0,'Car:'] = 'Ferrari'

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Name   Date     Car:
0  19GS  2-Dec  Ferrari
1  1A54  1-Feb      NaN
2  1AG5  1-Jan      NaN
3  1AH0  1-Feb      NaN
4  1AHG  4-Mar      NaN
```

Comment: I'm reading from a list of files, I can't set each column equal to ferrarri. Also, I noticed the variables don't match, but my problem is I don't know how to print a search

Comment: I edited my answer, if that's not what you want, you'll need to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: I thought it was pretty specific considering I said verbatim in my question I was searching files and I also had code indicating I was searching files. No disrespect, but you didn't read the question. And your answer doesn't answer it either.